# Display specific category laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I intend to rely on such database Developer how many categories there and give me a value.
I can do but doing echo in my index page he retorname the value 2 because there is a Developer and Design.
I intend it to me just one because I want to make an echo so the Developer.
My code is as follows

**Index**

```
<?php echo $portfolio['Developer']; ?>
```

**Controller**

```
    $portfolio = DB::table('portfolio')->where('portfolio.category','=','Developer')
                                       ->orWhere('portfolio.category','=','Design')
                                       ->count();
    return view('backend/dashboard.index', [
        'portfolio' => $portfolio, 
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided so but should not be the best way

**Index**

```
{{ DB::table('workshops')->where('workshops.category','=','Animation')->count() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You provide very little information. But assuming you have two where conditions, you might need to group by id (or whatever the primary key is). This typically looks like this:

```
DB::table('portfolio')
  ->where('portfolio.category','=','Developer')
  ->orWhere('portfolio.category','=','Design')
  ->groupBy('id') // Added groupBy
  ->count();
```

Also, I don't know what your models or database look like, but assuming your joining tables, it's natural to get 2 entries if you have 1 Portfolio with 2 Categories. This MySQL query will return 2 items too:

```
SELECT * FROM portfolio
LEFT JOIN categories
  ON categories.portfolio_id = portfolio.id
```

The same applies for many to many relations.